# Showing that a subspace is closed if and only if a particular set in closed in a Normed Linear Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a subspace of a normed linear space $X$. Then show that $M$ is closed if and only if $\{y \in M: \|y\| \leq1 \}$ is closed.
Can anyone prove it, I tried but couldn't.
Actually I am stuck in its solution, because of the following statement.

> Given M to be a subspace of X and if $y_n \to y$ where $y_n \in M$ and $r_n \to r$ where $r_n \in \mathbb{R}$ then is $\frac{y_n}{r_n} \to \frac{y}{r}$

Comment: The statement that you want to prove doesn't make sense.

Comment: You missed "is closed" at the end of the first paragraph.

Comment: And if your question is only about the final statement I'd suggest you to edit the title.

Comment: No, I would also love to get the answer to first question too.

Comment: In that case, you should add to your question the other parts of the proof that you don't understand (I assume you've been provided one), for us to help you accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is pretty much the same as proving

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{b}$$
if $a_n,b_n$ have limits $a$ and $b\neq0$. But in this proof instead of using the absolute value to measure how far two real numbers are, you use the norm on $X$ to measure the distance of two vectors.